# Upgrade to Artifactory OSS 5.6.3 MappingException

Tags: artifactory

I upgraded artifactory from 5.4.6 to 5.6.3 and I got the following exception.

How can I solve this issue?

```
2017-12-19 15:14:09,495 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.c.ConvertersManagerImpl:216) - Conversion failed. You should analyze the error and retry launching Artifactory. Error is: HTTP response status 401:{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","detail":"Failed to get cached permissions: ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: exception while creating object factory for org.jfrog.access.server.model.PermissionImpl","message":"HTTP 401 Unauthorized"}]}
2017-12-19 15:14:09,503 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:99) - Application could not be initialized: HTTP response status 401:{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","detail":"Failed to get cached permissions: ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: exception while creating object factory for org.jfrog.access.server.model.PermissionImpl","message":"HTTP 401 Unauthorized"}]}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.configure(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:224) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.6.3.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.access$2(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:186) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.6.3.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener$1.run(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:95) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.6.3.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: HTTP response status 401:{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","detail":"Failed to get cached permissions: ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: exception while creating object factory for org.jfrog.access.server.model.PermissionImpl","message":"HTTP 401 Unauthorized"}]}
    at org.artifactory.converter.ConvertersManagerImpl.handleException(ConvertersManagerImpl.java:223) ~[artifactory-common-5.6.3.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.converter.ConvertersManagerImpl.serviceConvert(ConvertersManagerImpl.java:171) ~[artifactory-common-5.6.3.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.refresh(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:232) ~[artifactory-core-5.6.3.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.<init>(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:120) ~[artifactory-core-5.6.3.jar:na]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientHttpException: HTTP response status 401:{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","detail":"Failed to get cached permissions: ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: exception while creating object factory for org.jfrog.access.server.model.PermissionImpl","message":"HTTP 401 Unauthorized"}]}
    at org.jfrog.access.client.http.AccessHttpClient.createRestResponse(AccessHttpClient.java:133) ~[access-client-core-3.0.4.jar:na]
    at org.jfrog.access.client.http.AccessHttpClient.restCall(AccessHttpClient.java:108) ~[access-client-core-3.0.4.jar:na]
    at org.jfrog.access.client.imports.ImportClientImpl.importSecurityEntities(ImportClientImpl.java:38) ~[access-client-core-3.0.4.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.importSecurityEntities(AccessServiceImpl.java:952) ~[artifactory-core-5.6.3.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy425.importSecurityEntities(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.artifactory.security.SecurityServiceImpl.importSecurityData(SecurityServiceImpl.java:2476) ~[artifactory-core-5.6.3.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.artifactory.storage.fs.lock.aop.LockingAdvice.invoke(LockingAdvice.java:76) ~[artifactory-storage-common-5.6.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy424.importSecurityData(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.artifactory.security.access.emigrate.AccessSecurityEmigratorImpl.emigrate(AccessSecurityEmigratorImpl.java:53) ~[artifactory-core-5.6.3.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.security.SecurityServiceImpl.convert(SecurityServiceImpl.java:321) ~[artifactory-core-5.6.3.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy424.convert(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.artifactory.converter.ConvertersManagerImpl.serviceConvert(ConvertersManagerImpl.java:167) ~[artifactory-common-5.6.3.jar:na]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

Comment: The error you are seeing is due to Artifactory not being able to communicate with the Access Server - which can be caused by several reasons...  most commonly check that you upgraded the `access.war` file and not just the `artifactory.war` file if this is a standalone installation.   Also removing the `adminToken` from the `artifactory.config.xml` (and renaming it to `artifactory.config.import.xml` to have the change reflected during startup) to rescue you from situations where you switched keys in access.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. I use my own tomcat (8.0.48) installation.
The etc folder looks like this:
artifactory.config.20170910.090525.yml
artifactory.config.bootstrap.1.xml
artifactory.config.bootstrap.2.xml
artifactory.config.bootstrap.xml
artifactory.properties
artifactory.system.properties
binarystore.xml
db.properties
export.security.1513700285735.xml
logback.original.xml
logback.xml
logback.xml.back
mimetypes.xml
plugins
security
security.20170910.085830.xml
ui

Comment: @danf I dont get any token. This ist from the access `request.log` **2017-12-20T04:20:22.631+0100|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|http://localhost:8081/access/api/v1/system/ping|200|0|202|JFrog Access Java Client/3.0.4
2017-12-20T04:20:22.686+0100|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|http://localhost:8081/access/api/v1/cert/root|200|0|36|JFrog Access Java Client/3.0.4
2017-12-20T04:20:23.048+0100|127.0.0.1|anonymous|POST|http://localhost:8081/access/api/v1/oauth/token|401|159|174|JFrog Access Java Client/3.0.4**

Answer (score 4):

Thank you Marco for this information. We (JFrog) would like to further investigate this matter over an online meeting, please reach out to us at support@jfrog.com and share with us what times (several) would work for you to start the session (including timezone). Make sure to send us a reference to this stackoverflow discussion. Once we get the email, we will send you the meeting details.